# How to retain value of field in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, vtl

I have one multi-select field whose values are coming from one table which has the following data.

```
Desc      | Code
----------------
India     | IN
Australia | AUS
Other     | OTH
```

**Requirement:** In that multi-select field if `Other` then a new field is getting populated as `Please specify (Others)` in which we will add some text value.

1. If I am selecting `India, Other, Australia` then the `Please specify (others)` should be enabled and the text which the user has written should be retained in please specify others field.
2. If I am selecting `India, Other` then removing `Other` and again selecting `other` then value of `Please specify(others)` should be blank.

**Problem:** When I am selecting `India, Other, Australia` then the `Please specify (others)` field value is getting nullified.

My attempt:

```js
function showHideOthers() {
    var selectedValue = $("#field_id_ui").val();
    if (null !== selectedValue) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedValue.length; i++) {
            if (selectedValue[i] == "OTH") {
                $("#Others_section").show();
            } else {
                $("#Others_section").hide();
                $("#Others_section").val("");
            }
        }
    } else {
        $("#Others_section").hide();
        $("#Others_section").val("");
    }
}
```

The fields for show and hide are taken from VTL file.

`"#field_id_ui"` - This is storing all the selected value in the form of array. For e.g [AUS, IN, OTH]

Comment: `function { ... } else { ... }` is not a valid statement

Comment: @GrafiCodeAppologies. I missed to add one if condition. Now added.

Comment: also, this: `$("#field_id_ui").val()` will give you ONLY the selected value, not the entire set of options (assuming that's a `<select>` element)

Comment: @GrafiCode I have verified from the console and it's giving me values in the form of an array. Hence, I wrote logic based on that.

Comment: Please provide the HTML that this code is supposed to work with. I didn't see code where *"a new field is getting populated"*.

Comment: Your logic will clear the value if any of the items in the list is not OTH.  Example AUS, IND, OTH - will clear the value because AUS is not OTH.

Comment: Did you make a mistake in point (2.)? Shouldn't that read `India, Australia`?

Comment: @trincot We are using VTL and ther I have defined the fields. Need help in writing the logic based on the requirement.

Comment: @trincot Yes it should read ```India, Australia```. A new field ```Please specify``` should be blank if I remove ```other``` from the multi-select field

Comment: I already understood that from your question, but jQuery works with HTML, so please show the HTML that jQuery is selecting with `$("#Others_section").show();` and the like... We shouldn't have to invent that.

Comment: I know nothing about "VTL" (added tag, but info didn't really help and there seem to be a few different ways to use it) - are you using it server-side to generate the HTML?  Or does it run in javascript?

Comment: @freedomn-m  I am using it on server-side

Comment: It was a leading question - if you're using it server-side, then you can provide the client-side *rendered* HTML, which is what the javascript is working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for hiding "other" depending on the contents of  `$("#field_id_ui").val()` is slightly wrong.  Here's a simple approach you can try.  See the docs for [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
function showHideOthers() {
    var selectedValue = $("#field_id_ui").val();
    // the rest of the code assumes that selectedValue is an array
    if (selectedValue.includes("OTH")) {
      $("#Others_section").show();
    } else {
      $("#Others_section").hide();
      $("#Others_section").val("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. There is one more scenario (pt (2)).
If I am selecting India, Other then removing Other and again selecting other then value of Please specify(others) should be blank.

So, to handle this I think we need last else part where if user removes ```others``` then again ```Please Specify(others)``` should not be displayed.

Comment: That should be handled with the above code.  `$(..multi select..).val()` will always return an array, never null - so the `.includes` will handle the case when you remove `others`  `$("#Others_section").val("");` clears the value when it's hidden, which matches your scenario above.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with this code:

```
if (selectedValue[i] == "OTH") {
```

which runs on *every* loops.  So if your selected values `["OTH", "IND"]` then the other input will be shown, then immediately hidden by the "IND" value.

Add a `break` inside the `if` and your code will work fine regardless of the order of select values.

*this assumes your HTML is built to match the provided javascript* (which we've not seen).

Updated code

```js
function showHideOthers() {
  var selectedValue = $("#field_id_ui").val();
  //console.log(selectedValue);

  if (null !== selectedValue) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedValue.length; i++) {
      if (selectedValue[i] == "OTH") {
        $("#Others_section").show();
        
        // with break; code stops as soon as OTH is found
        break;
      } else {
        $("#Others_section").hide();
        $("#Others_section").val("");
      }
    }
  } else {
    $("#Others_section").hide();
    $("#Others_section").val("");
  }
}

$("#field_id_ui").change(showHideOthers);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id='field_id_ui'>
  <option value="IND">India</option>
  <option value="OTH">Other</option>
</select>
<input id='Others_section' />
```

---

Snippet showing your code not working if `OTH` is not last value

```js
function showHideOthers() {
    //var selectedValue = $("#field_id_ui").val();
    //console.log(selectedValue);
    
    // other at the start fails
    selectedValue = ["OTH", "IND"];
    // other at the end works fine
    //selectedValue = ["IND", "OTH"];
    
    if (null !== selectedValue) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedValue.length; i++) {
          if (selectedValue[i] == "OTH") {
            $("#Others_section").show();
          } else {
                $("#Others_section").hide();
                $("#Others_section").val("");
            }
        }
    } else {
        $("#Others_section").hide();
        $("#Others_section").val("");
    }
}

//$("#field_id_ui").change(showHideOthers);
showHideOthers();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id='field_id_ui'>
<option value="IND">India</option>
<option value="OTH">Other</option>
</select>
<input id='Others_section'/>
```

Snippet showing your code working if `OTH` is the last value

```js
function showHideOthers() {
    //var selectedValue = $("#field_id_ui").val();
    //console.log(selectedValue);
    
    // other at the start fails
    //selectedValue = ["OTH", "IND"];
    // other at the end works fine
    selectedValue = ["IND", "OTH"];
    
    if (null !== selectedValue) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedValue.length; i++) {
          if (selectedValue[i] == "OTH") {
            $("#Others_section").show();
          } else {
                $("#Others_section").hide();
                $("#Others_section").val("");
            }
        }
    } else {
        $("#Others_section").hide();
        $("#Others_section").val("");
    }
}

//$("#field_id_ui").change(showHideOthers);
showHideOthers();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id='field_id_ui'>
<option value="IND">India</option>
<option value="OTH">Other</option>
</select>
<input id='Others_section'/>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I will try this out. Just one doubt why we have written ```$("#field_id_ui").change(showHideOthers);```. Any significance of this?

Comment: You didn't include how you were calling `showHideOthers` - having it call on the `select` changed seemed the obvious step.  As you already had [tag:jquery], made sense to add an event handler.